# Can we do a mySQL CASE with selecting tables after FROM?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am trying to select a table based on the value of the input in another table. lets say

```
SELECT tale0.*,class.*,hamburger.* 
FROM 
    CASE tale0.id=1 
        THEN class 
    END 
        CASE tale0.id=2 
            THEN hamburger
```

is this the way to go or is there a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use a CASE statement in the FROM clause. You will need to join in both tables, then pull the field from the relevant table based on the value:

```
SELECT
    tale0.*,
    CASE WHEN tale0.id = 1 THEN class.Column1 ELSE hamburger.Column1 END as Column1,
    CASE WHEN tale0.id = 1 THEN class.Column2 ELSE hamburger.Column2 END as Column2,
    ...
FROM
    table0, class, hamburger
-- include join conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is

```
SELECT TALE0.*, CLASS.*, NULL AS HF1, NULL AS HF2, NULL AS HF3
  FROM TALE0
  INNER JOIN CLASS
    ON CLASS.whatever = TALE0.whatever
UNION ALL
SELECT TALE0.*, NULL AS CF1, NULL AS CF2, NULL AS CF3, HAMBURGER.*
  FROM TALE0
  INNER JOIN HAMBURGER
    ON HAMBURGER.whatever = TALE0.whatever
```

You'd need to have as many HF1, HF2, HF3, etc fields as you have fields in HAMBURGER - and use the field names from HAMBURGER instead of HF1, HF2, HF3, etc. Likewise - CF1, CF2, etc should be replaced by the field names from CLASS.

Best of luck.